# Postman - Take the last id from response of a Get request and assign it to variable

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

I have to make a request to an endpoint with a non-existing id. The endpoint with all users returns a user list with the following structure:

```json
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "total": 100,
    "total_pages": 1000,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "a@b",
            "first_name": "a",
            "last_name": "b",
            "avatar": "jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to find the last returned id, increment it +1 and assign it to a variable.

Comment: https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/ this might be the thing that you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Lodash [last](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#last) method within the sandbox, to get the `id` of the last `object` in the `data` array.

```js
pm.globals.set('id', _.last(pm.response.json().data).id);
```